# PyQt4 not loading icons from .ui

Tags: python, qt, icons, pyqt4

I'm having a problem with icons in PyQt4:

I created an UI with Qt Designer, added some buttons with icons from the system theme, and then loaded the .ui file in a Python program, but the icons aren't visble (the buttons show their text).

If I use QIcon.fromTheme it works, but it doesn't load icons defined in the .ui file.

How can I make it load these icons, without manually loading them from code?

Comment: Works for me if I create a button and use "Set Icon From Theme...", then generate a runnable script with `pyuic4 -x test.ui`. What code are you using to load your ui file?

Comment: I'm using the uic module (`uic.loadUi("main.ui",self)`) because pyuic4 creates an empty file for me

Comment: Sounds like you might be doing something wrong somewhere. See my step-by-step answer below - does it work for you?

Comment: As I wrote before, pyuic creates an empty file (not really empty, it ends after the import), so I'm importing it directly with the PyQt4.uic module

Comment: After some further investigation, it seems there is a bug in PyQt (see my updated answer). As for `pyuic` creating an "empty" file: you're definitely doing something wrong. Did you try using the code in my answer?

Comment: Thanks, I solved it, I had the pyuic from PyQt3 instead of the one from PyQt4, I replaced it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

It looks like there's a bug in the `uic` package which prevents themed icons being loaded when `uic.loadUi` is used.

The offending code is in *`PyQt4/uic/icon_cache.py`* (around line 60):

```
# Handle a themed icon.
theme = iconset.attrib.get('theme')
if theme is not None:
    return self._object_factory.createQObject("QIcon.fromTheme",
            'icon', (as_string(theme), ), is_attribute=False)
```

The problem is the use of the `as_string` function, which tries to pass, e.g. `'_fromUtf8("face-smile")'` to `QIcon.fromTheme` instead of simply the icon name.

If you want this fixed, I would suggest reporting it on the [PyQt4 mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).

Note that the equivalent functionality works in PySide:

```
from PySide.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        QUiLoader().load('/tmp/test.ui', self)
```

---

Here's a simple breakdown of how to use `pyuic4` with a ui created in Qt Designer.

First, create your ui. Below is a minimal `ui` file which creates a button with a themed icon:

*`/tmp/test.ui`*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>110</x>
     <y>100</y>
     <width>92</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset theme="face-smile"/>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Next, use `pyuic4` to compile a python module from the `ui` file:

```
pyuic4 -o /tmp/test_ui.py /tmp/test.ui
```

*`/tmp/test_ui.py`*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '/tmp/test.ui'
#
# Created: Fri Sep 21 16:45:39 2012
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.9.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 100, 92, 25))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme(_fromUtf8("face-smile"))
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "PushButton", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Now import the compiled ui class into your application:

*`/tmp/test.py`*

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from test_ui import Ui_Form

class Window(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And finally, run the application:

```
python2.7 /tmp/test.py
```